# Как добавить php код в переменную для fopen. И как сделать транскипт переменной

Tags: javascript, php, html

Хочу сделать 2 страницы: 1 - шаблон, 2 - форма с полями для заполнения данных которые пойдут в шаблон и в бд. У меня возникло несколько проблем. Первая - я не могу в шаблон запихнуть php код:

```
<style>

    .profile-avatar{
    background: url(<?php
    // Получаем одну запись по её ID сессии
    $id = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
    $book = R::load('users', $id);
    echo $book->avatar;
    
    ?>);
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
        background-size: cover;
        border: 3px solid;
    border-color: #222;
    
    }`
```

он нужен для отображения аватарки профиля, так же не пропускается код с логином.
Вторая - Как сделать транскрипт переменной а после добавить к этому .php? Хочу сделать что-бы при ведении названия оно преобразовывалось в транскрипт и добавлялось .php, а после закинуть это как название для fopen.

### PHP

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST;
    $animename = $data['animename'];
    $headline = $data['headline'];
    $alt_names_list = $data['alt-names-list'];
    $year = $data['year'];
    $genre = $data['genre'];
    $original_source = $data['original-source'];
    $studio = $data['studio'];
    $producer = $data['producer'];
    $type = $data['type'];
    $number_of_episodes = $data['number-of-episodes'];
    $translation = $data['translation'];
    $description = $data['description'];
    $animenwame = ["11", "12"];
    $PATH = '../page/posters/'. time() . $_FILES['poster']['name']; 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['poster']['tmp_name'], $PATH);

    if (isset($data['ok_pognali']) )
    {    
            $page = R::dispense('animepage');
            $page->poster = $PATH;
            $page->headline = $data['headline'];
            $page->alt_names_list = $data['alt-names-list'];
            $page->year = $data['year'];
            $page->genre = $data['genre'];
            $page->original_source = $data['original-source'];
            $page->studio = $data['studio'];
            $page->producer = $data['producer'];
            $page->type = $data['type'];
            $page->number_of_episodes = $data['number-of-episodes'];
            $page->translation = $data['translation'];
            $page->description = $data['description'];
            R::store($page);

            echo '<div style="color: green;">Вы успешно создали страницу!</div><hr>';
        }else {

        }
$animepage = "
```

Comment: "название преобразовывалось в транскрипт и добавлялось .php, а после закинуть это как название для fopen." - это какая-то белиберда. Просьба описать желаемое поведение своими словами **без** употребления сложных и незнакомых терминов

Comment: @Ипатьев я так и пытался сделать) Чтобы если я ввел в поле "На Netflix вышел первый фильм с украинской озвучкой" оно преобразовалось в "na-netflix-vyshel-pervyy-film-s-ukrainskoy-ozvuchkoy" и в конце предложения добавлялось .php "na-netflix-vyshel-pervyy-film-s-ukrainskoy-ozvuchkoy.php" и в конце концов сделать из этой ссылки переменную $pagename. Что-бы после эту переменную я мог поставить в fopen "$f = fopen("../page/$pagename", "w" );"

Comment: зачем эту переменную ставить в $f = fopen?

Comment: @Ипатьев что-бы файл  php создался с названием заголовка страницы.

Comment: Понятно. Надо сначала понять что НИКТО НИКОГДА так не делает. Все такие ссылки обслуживает ОДИН php файл.тот самый шаблон, который получает данные из БД и выводит их. А как сделать такую ссылку гуглить по запросу РНР ЧПУ

Comment: @Ипатьев ок, спасибо